# Dash plotly store file in local folder (user's)

Tags: python-3.x, plotly, plotly-dash

How can we store a .json or dataframe (with pickle) to user's local folder using Dash app?

Comment: May be you want to allow user download any file which he wants? For example, using this [code](https://docs.faculty.ai/user-guide/apps/examples/dash_file_upload_download.html)

Comment: Yes, my application is a local application for now through the browser (for POC). The user will specify the folder location for files, then some other python module will process the files and then store them per users request in his local folder. The above seems to be very close to what I was looking for.